# Master Slave Pattern : Job Distribution

Tags: master-slave

Are there any standard algorithm to distribute the work among the slaves in the master/slave pattern? I have master which distributes job among the slaves via queue for now. But If I have to put job priority into the picture what kind of data structure/algorithm can be used?

Looking for some suggestion.

Thanks in advance,

Bibek Dawadi

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Heap/Priority Queue.